# Making a good base in War Dragons

Tags: war-dragons

How should I build a base that doesn’t get attacked so often?

Comment: Please don’t close this post as a duplicate. I deleted my first one so that I could start anew. The old one cannot even be viewed anymore.

Comment: Why does the way that building your base have anything to do with the amount of times you get attacked? Your answer also goes into detail about how to DEFEND your base, not reduce the amount of times it gets attacked. The title and question are different also.

Comment: Generally, we frown on users deleting and reposting their questions. It's usually seen as trying to shed down votes. As it stands, you're right back where you were before.

Comment: To answer you FoxMcCloud, I would like to point out that in this game, people can see the base they are choosing to attack before doing so. People who see compact bases often won’t attack them because they know it will probably take all of there top dragons to take it out; less people attacking your base. The way you build you build has an enormous impact on how often your base is attacked. Also, compact bases, for some reason, give less xp to the attacker’s dragons, so that’s another reason why people might not attack your base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

- Always stay compact; if you spread out, you will level up faster but it will be way, way easier for people to destroy your base.
- Always put a red and blue mage tower on every defending section of the base (every group of 5 towers).
- Only upgrade/build archer, cannon, ballista, lightning, and trebuchet towers if there is an reward for doing so.
- Most of the time,(except when you’re first starting) only use speed up timers during fortification frenzies: you will have the advantage in that event
- At the beginning, only work hard to upgrade 1 storm tower, your sheep farms and lumber mills, 1/2 red mages, 1/2 blue mages. Later, upgrade 1/2 fire turrets, 1 ice turret, 1 dark flak, and eventually another flak after you unlock more.

Here are 2 base layouts that after some hard thinking about how humans would react to certain things (my human psychology major really paid off!) and some testing of my own I came up with. One is more compact and thus, requires either a lot more patience, or a lot/ a lot more money. The number in the corner of each tower icon that shows which towers are a higher level are relative to that base (a tower with a 10 rating in one layout is not going to be the same lvl as one with a 10 rating on the other base). Also, in the picture key, I say that a certain icon represents blue mage/ice flak tower, but I recommend NOT actually using a ice flak; it doesn’t automatically do what mages do and building and upgrading one is just a bunch of resources that you didn’t use to upgrade something else. If you don’t understand the concept of upgrading a few towers a ton and not upgrading others as much, imagine that you have 5 towers that are lvl 40, but the rest of your towers are lvl 15-20. Those 5 towers alone can take out almost anything that players up to 20 levels higher than you can throw at you. Ok, here are the bases.[image: base layout 1 and 2]

As someone who reached lv 45 a while ago (unlocking the dark flak tower), and has had a few fortification frenzies since then, I can tell you that with the less compact of the 2 bases my base has not been attacked in over a week and has not been defeated in almost a month and a half. So yah...it works...(my original account doesn’t have this layout; It’s too far gone to save; and gets attacked 2-10 times a day)